# Doctrine event for executeQuery aren't fired

Tags: symfony, event-handling, doctrine

Using Doctrine with Symfony, I noticed that events (as in this [Symfony docs example](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)) for executeQuery are not fired: they fire only when dealing with entities but not direct SQL (Connection->executeQuery).

Am I missing something or is this how it should work by design?

Comment: It would improve your question if you could describe which events you did define how?

"This is how it should work by design." The events are "Doctrine ORM" while `executeQuery` is using "Doctrine DBAL", the database abstraction layer.

Comment: Nope.  Not missing anything.  Doctrine events are for the ORM layer.  Not the Database Access Layer (DBAL).